# How to remove different color borders

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This is the HTML

```
<body>
    <table border="10" id="pog">
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

this is the CSS

```
#pog{
    border-color:blue;
}
```

[Look at how the blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHAls.png)

the blue box is split with the two sides and they are different colors. How can I fix this?

Comment: Border styles are moderately flexible, the browser default vary per browser and per element. [Have a look at this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) and style your border however you want it to look.

Comment: It looks as though somewhere else is setting a border property. Have a look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility where you should be able to see where/who is doing this.